# Find Biggest and Smallest

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that takes an array of numbers and returns the biggest and smallest in an object.

If there is only one number in the array, that will be both the biggest and the smallest.

If there are no numbers in the array, it should return an empty object.

I have tried the following:

```
function findBiggestAndSmallest(numbers) {
  let obj = {};

  obj.biggest = Math.max(...numbers);

  obj.smallest = Math.min(...numbers);

  return obj;
 }
```

It is returning the biggest & smallest values within an object. However, when numbers is passed as an empty array I am getting:

AssertionError: expected { biggest: -Infinity, …(1) } to deeply equal {}

Could anyone assist where I am going wrong here please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: so add a check for an empty array and return what you want by default to be returned.

Comment: You can just `return { max: Math.max(...), min: Math.min(...) }` and skip the `obj` part. Even better, maybe just an array pair like `[ Math.min(...), Math.max(...) ]` or whatever order you prefer. Then call it `function minmax()` so you know what order to expect.

Comment: @tadman, you can by the assertion error `expected { biggest: -Infinity, …(1) } to deeply equal {}`, that the API is non-negotiable according to this test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bases cases before your main logic. This way you can return early from the function.

**Note:** Please use the [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) syntax instead of creating a new object and immediately assigning property/values. It is more succinct and clear what is happening.

```js
function findBiggestAndSmallest(numbers) {
  if (!numbers) return null;
  if (numbers.length === 0) return {};
  if (numbers.length === 1) {
    const [first] = numbers; /* destructure the first item */
    return { biggest: first, smallest: first };
  };
  return {
    biggest: Math.max(...numbers),
    smallest: Math.min(...numbers)
  };
};

const areEqual = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);

console.log(areEqual(null, findBiggestAndSmallest()));
console.log(areEqual({}, findBiggestAndSmallest([])));
console.log(areEqual({biggest:5,smallest:5}, findBiggestAndSmallest([5])));
console.log(areEqual({biggest:9,smallest:2}, findBiggestAndSmallest([5, 2, 9, 7])));
```

You could alternatively do the following since you checked the array bounds:

```js
if (numbers.length === 1) {
  return { biggest: numbers[0], smallest: numbers[0] };
};
```

You could optimize this by calling reduce. This way you only loop over the numbers once for O(n) time complexity.

```js
function findBiggestAndSmallest(numbers) {
  if (!numbers) return null;
  if (numbers.length === 0) return {};
  return numbers.reduce((result, n) => {
    if (n < result.smallest) {
      result.smallest = n;
    }
    if (n > result.biggest) {
      result.biggest = n;
    }
    return result;
  }, {
    biggest: -Number.MAX_VALUE,
    smallest: Number.MAX_VALUE
  });
};

const areEqual = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);

console.log(areEqual(null, findBiggestAndSmallest()));
console.log(areEqual({}, findBiggestAndSmallest([])));
console.log(areEqual({biggest:5,smallest:5}, findBiggestAndSmallest([5])));
console.log(areEqual({biggest:9,smallest:2}, findBiggestAndSmallest([5, 2, 9, 7])));
```

Comment: That's brilliant, just solved my problem. Thanks so much for your in depth and thorough explanation, really appreciated.